# How to solve- Write file to a specific directory through file picker asking for permission again and again in Android native Java?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

In my android native java project, I want one functionality that will create a .txt file by taking input from user. Then, while saving the file, we will use file picker to open and select one directory. Here, it will ask for permission to allow write in that directory.

**compileSdk = 34,
targetSdk = 34**

**Here's the code:**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bjit.fliecreateshowread.model.FileInfo;
import com.bjit.fliecreateshowread.adapter.FileInfoListAdapter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateFileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edtFileName;
    private EditText edtFileDesc;
    private Button btnSaveFile;

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    private static final int PICK_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    private FilePicker filePicker;

    private List<FileInfo> fileInfoList;
    private RecyclerView rvFileInformationList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_file);

        fileInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

        filePicker = new FilePicker();

        edtFileName = findViewById(R.id.edtFileName);
        edtFileDesc = findViewById(R.id.edtFileDesc);
        btnSaveFile = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveFile);
        rvFileInformationList = findViewById(R.id.rvFileInformationList);

        btnSaveFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                filePicker.pickDirectory(CreateFileActivity.this);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, you can proceed with file creation
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void createAndSaveTextFileOnSDCard(Intent data, String fileName, String fileDesc) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);

            if (documentFile != null && documentFile.exists()) {
                DocumentFile file = documentFile.createFile("text/plain", fileName + ".txt");

                try (OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file.getUri())) {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        String content = fileDesc;
                        outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
                        Log.e("##PATH", file.getUri().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(this, "File saved: " + file.getUri().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Read the file content after saving
                        String fileContent = readTextFile(file.getUri());
                        Log.e("##FILE_CONTENT", fileContent);

                        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName, file.getUri().toString());

                        showFilesInDirectory(documentFile.getUri());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving file: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Selected directory not found or does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid URI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private String readTextFile(Uri fileUri) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading file: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return content.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            createAndSaveTextFileOnSDCard(data, edtFileName.getText().toString(), edtFileDesc.getText().toString());
        }
    }


    private void showFilesInDirectory(Uri directoryUri) {
        DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, directoryUri);

        if (directory != null && directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()) {
            DocumentFile[] files = directory.listFiles();

            fileInfoList.clear();

            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                // Iterate through the list of files and display their names or perform other actions
                for (DocumentFile file : files) {
                    Log.e("##FILE_IN_DIRECTORY", "File Name: " + file.getName() + ", File URI: " + file.getUri());
                    // You can display the file names in a ListView, RecyclerView, or perform other actions here

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.getName(), file.getUri().toString());
                    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
                }

                rvFileInformationList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                FileInfoListAdapter adapter = new FileInfoListAdapter((ArrayList<FileInfo>) fileInfoList, CreateFileActivity.this);
                rvFileInformationList.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                Log.e("##FILE_IN_DIRECTORY", "No files in the directory");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("##FILE_IN_DIRECTORY", "Invalid directory or directory does not exist");
        }
    }


}
```

**------- Now the problem is ---------**

Even if I have allowed permission for one folder that I have already saved file and granted permission, whenever I am trying to save another file in the same directory, it is again asking me to allow permission. How can I avoid this and only ask for a single time permission for one folder?

[image]

Comment: You only have to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE (or equivalent) once if you take persitable uri permission on the obtained uri. You should not use ACTION_OPEN_DICUNENT_TREE twice. Why you do? FYI: i did not read your code yet. First wanne know what goes on.

Comment: I have used that twice because, one time I need to save file by picking up specific directory, and the 2nd one is for retrieving file information from picked up directory.

Comment: You can use it as often as you want. But it is not needed. And it looks as if it has nothing to do with your problem. If you use the action again and choose the same directory again you are asked to allow. Indeed that happens. You can do nothing about it. For that you did not have to post code.